# Fernando wears three colours of socks: red, blue and white. Is there a fewest number of socks he could take to guarentee a red pair?

Tags: combinatorics

Fernando wears three colours of socks: red, blue and white. The total amount of socks he has are undisclosed. Is there a fewest number of socks he could take to guarantee a red pair?

Comment: The number of blue socks plus the number of white socks plus two.

Comment: He can't; there might only be one red sock.  There might not be any at all.

Comment: If he can *see* the socks (and isn't colorblind), the answer is $2$....

Comment: @MJD Especially if Fernando really *wants* a red pair, then any red socks he might have will be the ones that disappear in the washer and dryer.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum number to guarantee that two socks are of the same color is $4$, because three of them might have different colors and the fourth one surely has the same color as a previously chosen one.

In order to be sure that two red socks are picked up, the worst case is that *no* red sock is extracted, just blue and white ones, until two red ones are picked. If $b$ is the number of blue socks, $w$ the number of white socks, the minimum is $b+w+2$.